# Need to add two numbers in MFC with using CString veriables

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to add  two numbers in  MFC with using CString variables.
For example: 
CString m_nedit1,
CString m_nedit2 and I need to store it in CString m_nedit3.

All three edit controls are value type(CString) not a control type

Please provide your answer.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking. Do you have two edit boxes in a dialog, and you want to retrieve the text from the dialogs as numeric values, and you want to add those numbers?

Comment: Yes, I have three edit boxes and button in a dialog, when double click the  button edit1 and edit 2 values should be calculated and displayed it on 3rd edit control.All three edit controls are value type(CString) not a control type.

Comment: Are the numbers supposed to be integers or floating point?

Comment: They should be value type of type `int` or `doulbe` but not of type `CString`.

Comment: I dont want define any int or float types,i want define only CString type and later on need to convert it to int type..

Comment: An edit control cannot be a CString. It can be *copied* to or from a CString, but you seem to be confused about how Windows and MFC work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question on [Dialog Data Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange?view=vs-2019)

On the button press you want to use [`UpdateData(TRUE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#updatedata) to set the CString control values `m_nedit1` and `m_nedit2`.

Then you build your `m_nedit3` string in whatever way you mean by "calculate". Then you synchronise the change back to the dialog controls with `UpdateData(FALSE)`.

For example lets presume you meant concatenation:

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
m_nedit3 = m_nedit1 + m_nedit2;
UpdateData(FALSE);
```

You should handle the case `UpdateData(FALSE)` returning FALSE. This would mean the sync failed accordingly to any DDV conditions you may have imposed, e.g. maximum string length.

Answer (score 0):

While you can synchronize to an int type, using CString is possible.  You need to convert to int add, then convert back to CString.

```
UpdateData();
int nAnswer = _ttoi(m_nedit1) + _ttoi(m_nedit2);
m_nedit3.Format(_T("%d"),nAnswer);
UpdateData(FALSE);
```